# Skip new tasks if the queue is not empty. Swift

Tags: swift, macos, concurrency, swift4

I have a piece of code that spams long running tasks 5-6 times per second. Each task takes some time to finish. I want to ignore all the other tasks while 1 is being executed. After it finishes a fresh one should take its place.

There are a bunch of tools being used for concurrency in Swift 4.2. What would work the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving of this problem you can use **GCD** or **Operation**. In case that you have describ I would use **Operation**. Using this approach you can have a bit more user friendly control over **Operation** that are executing (stoping, cancelling....).

Small example:

```
let queue  = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

queue.addOperation { print("") }
queue.addOperation { print("") }
queue.addOperation { print("") }
```

In this case operations are executed one by one.